# celery recurring task not executing

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

My periodic task is never executed.  What am I missing?  I have the RabbitMQ service running.  I also have flower running and the celery worker is showing up there.

I find it frustrating that there are a ton of examples on how to use celery with Django, but most of those are old versions which I believe don't apply to the latest release.

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'solar_secured.settings')

app = Celery('solar_secured', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

tasks.py

```
from asset_monitor.process_raw import parse_rawdata

from datetime import timedelta
from celery.task import periodic_task

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=5))
def parse_raw():
    parse_rawdata()
```

started celery worker

```
C:\dev\solar_secured>manage.py celeryd
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.6-py2.7.egg\celery\apps\worker.py:159:
CDeprecationWarning:
Starting from version 3.2 Celery will refuse to accept pickle by default.

The pickle serializer is a security concern as it may give attackers
the ability to execute any command.  It's important to secure
your broker from unauthorized access when using pickle, so we think
that enabling pickle should require a deliberate action and not be
the default choice.

If you depend on pickle then you should set a setting to disable this
warning and to be sure that everything will continue working
when you upgrade to Celery 3.2::

    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']

You must only enable the serializers that you will actually use.


  warnings.warn(CDeprecationWarning(W_PICKLE_DEPRECATED))

[2013-12-16 11:26:19,302: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cel
ery-3.1.6-py2.7.egg\celery\apps\worker.py:159: CDeprecationWarning:
Starting from version 3.2 Celery will refuse to accept pickle by default.

The pickle serializer is a security concern as it may give attackers
the ability to execute any command.  It's important to secure
your broker from unauthorized access when using pickle, so we think
that enabling pickle should require a deliberate action and not be
the default choice.

If you depend on pickle then you should set a setting to disable this
warning and to be sure that everything will continue working
when you upgrade to Celery 3.2::

    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']

You must only enable the serializers that you will actually use.


  warnings.warn(CDeprecationWarning(W_PICKLE_DEPRECATED))


 -------------- celery@DjangoDev v3.1.6 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-2008ServerR2-6.1.7601-SP1
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> broker:      amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> app:         solar_secured:0x2cd4b00
- ** ---------- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
- *** --- * --- .> events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.6-py2.7.egg\celery\fixups\django.py:224
: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setti
ng in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2013-12-16 11:26:20,512: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cel
ery-3.1.6-py2.7.egg\celery\fixups\django.py:224: UserWarning: Using settings.DEB
UG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2013-12-16 11:26:20,512: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@DjangoDev ready.
```

started celery beat

```
C:\dev\solar_secured>manage.py celery beat
celery beat v3.1.6 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2013-12-16 14:18:48,206: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a scheduler to execute [periodic tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). You can use Celery's Beat which is default scheduler. Use following command to use beat `python manage.py celery worker -B`

Comment: When I was attempting to start celery beat, it was erroring off saying the process was already running because of the presence of the file celerybeat.pid.  When I deleted this file and executed manage.py celery beat, my jobs began to run as scheduled.   The format you use above with the -B option does not work with the latest version of celery.